# Как явно ускорить процесс стороннего приложения Linux

Tags: linux, многопоточность, планировщик-задач

У меня долго выполнялась задача в pgadmin, по pid я поднял ей приоритет для планировщика чтобы ускорить:

```
sudo renice 20 -p pid
```

она стала немного больше есть ресурсов(+3%), но ощутимого ускорения это не дало. Pid я нашел так :

```
ps alx | grep pgadmin
```

и выбрал ту, у которой время исполнения самое больше
Потом поднял приоритет всем задачам, которые связаны с pgadmin, то есть её потоки тоже захватил. Но все эти танцы ощутимого эффекта не дали.\

(UPD: говорить об "ощутимом эффекте" нельзя, т.к. я не видел промежуточного результата и скорость его формирования. Позже в эксперименте с более легкими задачами я обнаружил, что если всем процессам связанных с вашей задачей поднять приоритет по pid, то выполняться будет действительно быстрее)


Дополнительные сведения:

-У меня Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

-Процессор был загружен на 9%.

-Интересующий нас процесс pgadmina работал в 1 ядро, изредка в 2, все 15 остальных были заняты почти ничем. На общей картине проц был занят на 8-9%, в которых pgadmin занимал 6,3-6,4%( это как раз примерно 1/16 от всей мощности, то есть 1 из 16 ядер). Через htop я в этом убедился: он показывает 16 процессоров, и pgadmin заваливал на 98-103%, то есть на 1 ядро сильно и изредка на 2).

-Ресурсы для ускорения были в избытке(Кол-во свободный ресурсов в несколько раз превышали кол-во тех ресурсов, что были заняты в этот момент) и по оперативной памяти и по процессору.

-Процесс никак не связан с получением данных из сети.Запрос к базе уже был выполнен. Сервер базы почти не испытывал нагрузки и работал в штатном режиме.

Подскажите, как еще можно ускорить процесс стороннего приложения?

Comment: только завершить другие процессы)

Comment: Изменение приоритета влияет на количество предоставляемых процессу квантов времени CPU. Если же задача тормозится из-за ввода-вывода (например, по сети), то изменение приоритета ничего не даст.

Comment: @avp данная задача никак не связана с передачей данных по сети. Запрос уже был выполнен. В запросе в каждой записи (20к) содержалась геолокация, мне надо было на карте отобразить это. 1к точек строилось 3 минуты, 5к точек - минут 15, 20к точек так и не построились за 1,5 часа.

Comment: @eri  у меня этот процесс долбит в одно ядро, изредка на 2, все 15 остальных были заняты ничем. На общей картине проц был занят на 8-9%, в которых pgadmin занимал 6,3-6,4%( это как раз примерно 1/16 от всей мощности). Через htop я в этом убедился: он показывает 16 процессоров, и pgadmin заваливал на 98-103%, то есть на 1 ядро сильно и изредка на 2)

Comment: @SpaceResearcher, вы ничего не рассказали про то, что делает это приложение. Если достоверно не знаете, то можно попробовать запусть его под strace, посмтореть lsof-ом, посмотреть в top что происходит при его работе и т.п. Потом уже можно делать предположения об его ускорении

Comment: Вот теперь, видя ваш коммент с описанием ситуации с процессорами можно точно сказать, что изменение его приоритета ни на что не повлияет

Comment: @SpaceResearcher сколько ядер долбить решает разработчик приложения, а не само приложение и не ос

Comment: @eri, да, согласен звучит логично, только почему тогда иногда он занимал больше,чем 1 ядро?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак, только если разогнать процессор, повысив его частоту работы